# in windows, how to have non-blocking stdin that is a redirected pipe?

Tags: c++, c, windows, stdin, pipe

I have a Windows C program that gets its data through a redirected `stdin` pipe, sort of like this:

```
./some-data-generator | ./myprogram
```

The problem is that I need to be able to read from `stdin` in a non-blocking manner.  The reason for this is that (1) the input is a data stream and there is no `EOF` and (2) the program needs to be able to abort its `stdin`-reading thread at any time.  `fread` blocks when there's no data, so this makes it very difficult.

In Unix this is no problem, as you can set the blocking mode of a file descriptor with `fcntl` and `O_NONBLOCK`.  However, `fcntl` doesn't exist on windows.

I tried using `SetNamedPipeHandleState`:

```
    DWORD mode= PIPE_READMODE_BYTE|PIPE_NOWAIT;
    BOOL ok= SetNamedPipeHandleState(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &mode, NULL, NULL);
    DWORD err= GetLastError();
```

but this fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (`0x5`).

I'm not sure what else to do.  Is this actually impossible (!) or is it just highly obfuscated?  The resources on the net are rather sparse for this particular issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order apprach, check there is input ready to read:

- For console mode, you can use GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents().
- For pipe redirection, you can use PeekNamedPipe()

Comment: PeekNamedPipe was what I was looking for... This allows you to then call ReadFile so that it doesn't block.

Answer (score 1):

You could use async I/O to read from the handle, such as the ReadFileEx() WIN32 call. Use CancelIo() to terminate reading in the absence of input.

See MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365468(VS.85).aspx

Comment: That won't work if the handle is to an anonymous pipe - as it will be in the example give in the question. Overlapped (async) I/O is not possible with anonymous pipes.